# I can't install psycopg2 in my virtual environment

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

I bought a book Django for professionals and I am currently on 2. chapter PostgreSQL. I have django installed in my virtual environment and my project is in docker as you can see from code below.

When I try to install psycopg I get an error:
**Warning: Python 3.10 was not found on your system...
Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
$ pipenv --python path/to/python**.

I run command: **docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5**

My Dockerfile is

```sh
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml file is

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
    - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the first line of your Dockerfile in your post. The `FROM` statement.

Comment: You shouldn't normally install things in running containers; anything you `docker-compose exec ... pipenv install` will get lost as soon as that container exits.  Do you need to add the dependency to your Pipfile instead?  Do you need Docker here, or will a host-based virtual environment be easier to work with?

Comment: change 3.9 to 3.7, in both `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm a bit late...bought the same book and had the same issue. As @David Maze mentioned exit out of your container **docker-compose down**, don't be inside your venv and install *psycopg2* with pipenv:

```
pipenv install psycopg2
```

Afterwards restart your container and everything should be working fine. You have to write it in to your **Pipfile**, not into your active - running - container.

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: 'docker build . ' and 'docker-compose up -d' would do the same.